# I want to run the selenium webdriver code without using the eclipse is that possible?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run the selenium webdriver code without using the eclipse is that possible if its yes please explains how it can be achieved.

Comment: Use Maven. See this link : http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/creating-and-running-a-simple-selenium-webdriver-test/2011-09-15

Comment: There are too many possible answers. What language are you using? Are you going to be running this from your local machine, or from a build machine? Is it going to be scheduled, or just double-click on an icon?

Comment: I want to run it from my local machine and click on an icon

Answer (score 1):

You can run through command line interface:

```
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" SeleniumWebDriverExample.java
```

If you have the jar file in different location , give the absolute / relative location of the classpath.