# Java Selenium Run through Command Prompt CMD Windows Without IDE

Tags: java, windows, selenium

I'm using Windows but I don't have access to install Eclipse IDE or others so the only way is to run selenium through command prompt, I know there are similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058790/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375085/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367523/) but that not solved my problem. And here are my script

**mySelenium.java**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class mySelenium {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // Open Google
    driver.get("https://www.example.com");

    // Close browser
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

when I run following in CMD

```
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" mySelenium.java
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" mySelenium
```

I get error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class mySelenium.java
```

I don't understand why it cannot found the `main` because in my script here is main, so what the command that I need to run it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" mySelenium.java
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" mySelenium
```

It should be:

```
**javac** -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" mySelenium.java
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" mySelenium
```

You wrote java instead of javac.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add current directory to your classpath.

```
java -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar;." mySelenium
```